banner/motd for root shell?
Is there a common way I can show a banner when a user sudo -s or doas -s on a host?
I don't mean ssh/login banner, but starting a root shell via those methods.

You do not mention which shell you use. In this answer bash is assumed. However, similar methods can be used with any shell with a bit of adaption.
With bash a message can be outputted by adding commands to .bashrc (~/.bashrc).
The command "if [ "$PS1" ]; then" tests for an interactive shell. Then the command "if [[ "$SUDO_COMMAND" == "$SHELL" || -n "$DOAS_USER" ]]; then" tests if started by sudo or doas. If so a message is outputted with echo.
Output example:
prompt> sudo -s
[sudo] password for user:

  You are now running with root privileges.
  Be careful!

prompt> 

Example .bashrc:
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

# If running interactively, then:
if [[ -n "$PS1" ]]; then

  if [[ "$SUDO_COMMAND" == "$SHELL" || -n "$DOAS_USER" ]]; then
    echo -e '\n  You are now running with root privileges.\n  Be careful!\n'
  fi

  # enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
  if [[ "$TERM" != "dumb" ]]; then
    if [[ "$TERM" = "xterm1" ]]; then
      eval $(env TERM=xterm dircolors -b)
    else
      eval $(dircolors -b)
    fi
  fi

  alias ls='ls --color=auto'

fi


Thank you. I was fishing for a way tied to sudo/doas/login/polkit/userctl etc. Relying on the shell is too fragile.
